# How to enable App Service Mobile App SSO for UWP

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, uwp

I am building a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app that uses the Azure App Service Mobile App backend as well as the user's OneDrive account. I have 2 requirements for authentication:

1. If the user is logged in to their UWP device with a Microsoft account (e.g. Windows 10) then I don't want them to be presented with a login prompt (i.e. Single Sign On, re-using their Microsoft account credentials).
2. I want to have a single authentication event across Azure & OneDrive, i.e. the user authorises once and I re-use that token for both services.

I did this in Windows Phone 8 with an Azure Mobile Service by logging in with the Live SDK and then passing the returned token to the `MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync()` method, however I can't get this to work in UWP with an Azure Mobile App. When I call that same method I receive a `401 Unauthorised` response.

- I have associated my UWP app with the store and set up the
  application at the Microsoft Account Developer Centre, including
  adding the redirect URI from the Azure Mobile App.
- I have set up the Azure App Service Mobile App, including adding the
  Client ID & Secret from the Microsoft Account Developer Centre.
- I have tried numerous ways to retrieve the token, including the
  `OnlineIdAuthenticator`, `WebAuthenticationCoreManager` and
  `WebAuthenticationBroker`. None has worked so far.

I currently use the following code in a class `LiveAuthenticationService` to retrieve an access token:

```
public async Task<bool> LoginAsync()
{
    AccessToken = null;
    bool success = false;
    OnlineIdAuthenticator onlineIdAuthenticator = new OnlineIdAuthenticator();
    EventWaitHandle waithandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    OnlineIdServiceTicketRequest serviceTicketRequest = new OnlineIdServiceTicketRequest(scopes, "DELEGATION");
    UserIdentity result = await onlineIdAuthenticator.AuthenticateUserAsync(serviceTicketRequest);
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result?.Tickets[0]?.Value))
    {
        currentUserId = result.SafeCustomerId;
        AccessToken = result.Tickets[0].Value;
        success = true;
        waithandle.Set();
    }
    else
    {
        await logger.LogErrorAsync("Error signing in to Microsoft Live",
                                    new Dictionary<string, string> { { "errorCode", result?.Tickets[0]?.ErrorCode.ToString() } });
    }
    waithandle.WaitOne(10000);  //10 second timeout

    return success;
}
```

And then this to attempt to login to my Azure Mobile App with that token, which uses `LiveAuthenticationService` from above:

```
private async Task RefreshUserIdAndAccessToken()
{
    try
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<MobileServiceUser>();

        var authService = new LiveAuthenticationService();
        await UiDispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                    async () =>
                                    {
                                        try
                                        {
                                            await authService.LoginAsync();
                                            var jsonAuthenticationToken = JObject.Parse(@"{""authenticationToken"": """ + authService.AccessToken + @"""}");
                                            tcs.SetResult(await mobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount, jsonAuthenticationToken));
                                        }
                                        catch (Exception ex)
                                        {
                                            tcs.SetException(ex);
                                        }
                                    });

        var user = await tcs.Task;
        currentUserId = user.UserId;
        AccessToken = user.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await logger.LogExceptionAsync(ex,
                                        Constants.LOGGING_DATAKEY_REFRESHACCESSTOKENFAILURE,
                                        currentUserId);
        currentUserId = null;
        AccessToken = null;
    }
}
```

As stated this results in a 401 Unauthorised response from Azure. I have run Fiddler and the request seems to be correct, the expected authentication token is included in a JSON payload with the request.

**UPDATE**
One thing I can see is that the token issued by the code above is almost 900 characters long, all in the form `YnElFkAAcK8bRSQab/FK+PT5n/wA4CPU...`, while the token issued if I let Azure Mobile App handle the authentication, i.e. call `MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync()` without passing a token, is only about 350 characters long and in the form `hbGciOi.eyJmdWWxsIiwiRGJn...` (notice the period towards the beginning).

This issue is really causing me problems now. I can't release the app without the authentication working and I can't figure out how to fix it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a tough one for me to solve as I was facing this problem too.

The most important part is the `OnlineIdServiceTicketRequest` the request should look like this:

```
var mobileServicesTicket = new OnlineIdServiceTicketRequest("https://yourmobileservice.azure-mobile.net/", "JWT");
```

Note that we are specifying your endpoint and also requesting a JWT token instead of delegation. This will get the 350ish character token you were looking for.

Here is a full code sample of what I'm doing:

```
public async Task<bool> LoginAsync()
{
  var authenticator = new Windows.Security.Authentication.OnlineId.OnlineIdAuthenticator();
  var mobileServicesTicket = new Windows.Security.Authentication.OnlineId.OnlineIdServiceTicketRequest("https://yourendpoint.azure-mobile.net/", "JWT");

  var ticketRequests = new List<OnlineIdServiceTicketRequest>() { mobileServicesTicket };

  var authResult = await authenticator.AuthenticateUserAsync(ticketRequests, CredentialPromptType.PromptIfNeeded);

  if ((authResult.Tickets.Count == 1) && (authResult.Tickets[0].ErrorCode == 0))
  {                            
      var accessToken = authResult.Tickets[0];          
      var res = await _mobileServiceClient.LoginWithMicrosoftAccountAsync(accessToken.Value);

      return true;
  }
  else
  {          
    return false;
  }
}
```

`_mobileServiceClient` is injected into the class and is a reference to `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient` object within the `WindowsAzure.MobileServices` library.

I actually ended up writing a blog article about this problem here http://jshapland.com/single-sign-on-with-azure-mobile-services-in-a-uwp-app/

Comment: what nuget package did you use? In the code you provided you are referencing a local variable _mobileServiceClient. Is this from the 'WindowsAzure.MobileServices' nuget or from the 'Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client' nuget?

Comment: I updated my answer with where that reference came from. It's the WindowsAzure.MobileServices nuget package.

Comment: hmm. How do you invoke the LoginAsync? When I'm debugging, it stalls on the "authenticator.AuthenticateUserAsync" line... I'm getting an exception that says "Authentication target is invalid or not configured correctly."

Comment: Did you configure the single sign on provider in Azure Mobile services? Some documentation on how to do that can be found here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-store-dotnet-adal-sso-authentication/

Comment: I got it working by switching from using WindowsAzure.MobileServices to Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client. We are in a very confusing time with Mobile apps and mobile services. It would help if Microsoft provided updated documentation for UWP and Mobile Apps. Oh well!

Comment: This is really helpful but I'm getting the same "Authentication target is invalid or not configured correctly" error as @emseetea when I call `AuthenticateUserAsync`. I'm using `OnlineIdServiceTicketRequest("https://[appName].azurewebsites.net/", "JWT")`. Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you're callback urls are correctly setup in the Live Services Site (frustratingly hard to get to place). The Redirect URL should be https://[your-app].azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/microsoftaccount/callback if you are using Microsoft account login. Also double check if there is any extra whitespace in the secret key or client id in the mobile app authentication config on Azure. I suffered from all of these gotchyas.

Comment: Thanks @emseetea but I've checked all of those and they seem to be correct. I will try to delete the app from the Live Services Site and re-create it.

Comment: Fixed! I had to set `Target domain:` in the Live Services Site to be `[your-app].azurewebsites.net` Thanks!